# Am having a problem with my JavaScript log out code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to logout a user using a JavaScript code but it keeps loading without logging out.What have I done wrong?

I have tried changing the function itself but it still wouldn't log out.The loader just keeps on running.

```
this is the code
```

```
logout.html(loader);
   $.get("modules/"+role+"/"+role+".php",{
         },function(pagedata){
         logout.show().html(pagedata);        
  });
```

I'm expecting the code to logout and take me back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
$.get()
```

method requests data from the server with an HTTP GET request.
The required URL parameter specifies the URL you wish to request.
The optional callback parameter is the name of a function to be executed if the request succeeds.

```
$.get(URL,callback);
```

so change your code :

```
    logout.html(loader);
     $.get("modules/"+role+"/"+role+".php",function(pagedata){
     logout.show().html(pagedata);        
      });
```